# magento custom options price calculation - height * width

Tags: php, magento, calculator

I'm building a webshop with Magento and like to add a product with three custom options: select option, width and height.

For instance, I sell doors. The size of the door shoul be chosen by the costumer. In order to accomplish that, I created 3 custom options in all the simple products: type of door with a fixed price, width and height.

What i would like is to be able to calculate the price of the type of door based on the size (width & height). So the fixed price of one of the type of doors is 1000 / 1000 mm and one someone put 1000 / 2000 that it calculates it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a configurable product with all 3 above attributes as configurable attributes. Assign the calculated prices to the individual simple products. When customer will select the type, width and height, the respective simple product with these configurations will be selected and the its price will be reflected in cart without any overrides. :)